# Is there a way to use an enum as type in Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I tried doing something like `@param {window.MyNamespace.MyEnum} myVar`, but the compiler complained about a `JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation. Unknown type window.MyNamespace.MyEnum`.

Should I have done an `@typedef`on the enum, or just use `@param {number}`, if my enum is `@enum {number}`? I really prefer the enum thing, as other values aren't really allowed.

```
(function (MyNamespace) {
  /**
   * @enum {number}
   */
  MyNamespace.MyEnum = {
    FOO: 1,
    BAR: 2,
    BAZ: 3
  }
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {Object} foo
   */
  MyNamespace.MyClass = function (foo) {
    this.foo = foo
  }
  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {MyNamespace.MyClass} bar
   */
  MyNamespace.MyOtherClass = function (bar) {
    this.bar = bar
  }
  /**
   * @param {MyNamespace.MyEnum} baz
   */
  MyNamespace.MyOtherClass.prototype.someMethod = function (baz) {
  }
})(window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {})
```

Comment: Unless you defined the namespace `window`, `window` should not be part of the type declarations.

Comment: I had defined the namespace as written in a jQuery enterprise article: [link](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/), but closure compiler was unable to find the types, so I moved the argument part of the namespace definition into the function.

Comment: Do you still get an error with the code you posted?

Comment: Yes, still the `JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR`.

Comment: But it's different right? Because you don't use `@param {window.MyNamespace.MyEnum}` anywhere in your code.

Comment: The difference now is that I gave window.MyNamespace to the self-invoking function as parameter, but changed the `@param` declaration to `MyNamespace.MyEnum`. However the error remains, be it me using `window.MyNamespace.MyEnum` or `MyNamespace.MyEnum`. I'm questioning whether it is possible at all to use an enum as type declaration in Google Closure Compiler.

Comment: I tried a simple example (  `/** * @type {MyNamespace.MyEnum} */ window.foo = MyNamespace.MyEnum.FOO;` (sorry for the formatting) with http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home and it worked fine.

Comment: The simple optimisations should work fine, as they don't look at the annotated type stuff. It simply removes whitespace and comments, and renamed local methods. It's the advanced optimisations I'm interested in.

Comment: I selected advanced optimization. If I use `Foo.MyEnum` instead it throws a warning.

Comment: I'm still getting `JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation.` Could you post the full code you used with that?

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/fkling/6213239. Maybe it is indeed a problem with the wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliasing types using a function parameter is not well supported in Closure-compiler. Use the `--output_wrapper` flag to enclosure your code after compilation. The following code compiles correctly:

```
/** @const */
var MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};

/** @enum {number} */
MyNamespace.MyEnum = {
  FOO: 1,
  BAR: 2,
  BAZ: 3
};
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {Object} foo
 */
MyNamespace.MyClass = function (foo) {
  this.foo = foo
};
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {MyNamespace.MyClass} bar
 */
MyNamespace.MyOtherClass = function (bar) {
  this.bar = bar
};
/** @param {MyNamespace.MyEnum} baz */
MyNamespace.MyOtherClass.prototype.someMethod = function (baz) {};
```

Comment: Okay, it compiles correctly, but the parameter type checking will be limited to the enum type, and not to the different enum values. If you call MyNameSpace.MyOtherClass.someMethod(4), it won't give you a warning even if 4 is not a defined value in the enum... But maybe i'm too strict about that.

Comment: @Sebastien Enums are not validated nor intended to be used in that way. It is intended to use the symbol `MyNamespace.MyEnum.BAR` and the compiler will replace it with the value during compilation.

Comment: Right, but still, it won't gives you a warning if you call this method with a number, even if you specified the parameter type as "MyNamespace.MyEnum" (but well, i haven't found a solution for that either...)

Comment: @Sebastien That behavior is by design. I suggest you ask another question with the details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Sebastien The compiler's default warning level won't report type mismatch issues. You need to use `--warning_level VERBOSE`, which [enables type checking](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150609/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/WarningLevel.java#L109). Calling `someMethod(4)` will then trigger a compiler warning: *"Actual parameter 1 does not match formal parameter. Found: `number`. Required: `MyNamespace.MyEnum<number>`"*